# Get WordPress Post in my own PHP application

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services

I am trying to make an `PHP` app that will simply display the post categories and posts (title, thumbnail, Content) from my `WordPress` website.

Can any one help me, please.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Please read [How to Ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and update your question with the code you have tried in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and details of the exact problem so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access few of the tables

- Taxonomy (It includes all categories, sub categories and tags)
- Posts (it includes all version of posts)
- Post_Options (it includes all options/variables of that post)

So you will be needed to access these above tables as per your need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed I need a webservice that reads the articles published on my wordpress website and publish them automatically in my PHP application.. any help please

Comment: I think you are looking for this. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251527/wp-rest-api-filter-by-category-1-and-category-2